# Android ICS 4.1 - USB Ethernet - How to toggle Ethernet connectivity state?

Tags: android, toggle, state, ethernet

I purchased an android device (Rikomagic MK 802IIIs) to connect to my TV.
I have developed a simple application that requires an internet connection (currently connected via a USB Ethernet adapter).

My issue is that the Ethernet connection is found (MAC Address has been set) however my IP and other details are not configuring on boot (0.0.0.0).

If I toggle the Ethernet state, it picks up the details and everything works fine again.

I believe that the issue may be due to the device, so I was wondering if anyone knows of how I could 'Toggle' the Ethernet connectivity via code.

I have an application that executes on boot so essentially I will be placing it there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Android HDMI TV stick. Because it wasn't my intention to write an own app for this I had a look at scripting possibilities.

Running `dhcpcd eth0` in a root terminal first seemed to work but caused Android's settings app to crash. So I set up a static IP in Android's ethernet settings and just disable and enable the device by running `ifconfig eth0 down ; ifconfig eth0 up`. This works reliably.

To run this command every time after boot with su privileges I use [SManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.tools.scriptmanager&hl=en).

I don't know if this is a solution for you but if not you could toggle ethernet state simply by executing `ifconfig eth0 up` and `ifconfig eth0 down` with root privileges from your own app:

- [Any way to run shell commands on android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350283/any-way-to-run-shell-commands-on-android-programmatically)
- [android : how to run a shell command from within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054973/android-how-to-run-a-shell-command-from-within-code)
- [Running shell commands from app [Rooted]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802810/running-shell-commands-from-app-rooted)

Comment: problem is, that's not a "toggle". Desirable would be something like "if eth0 up then ifconfig eth0 down else ifconfig eth0 up". I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Don't have a system to test it right now, but maybe ifconfig up/down gives you different result codes you could check for if the interface is already up/down. Have you tried?